# Strange white bar shows, when using TTThumbsViewController with iOS 5 SDK

Tags: three20, ios5, xcode4.2, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I write an iPhone application using Three20 library to display thumbnail images. At first I build the app using XCode 4.0.2 with iOS SDK 4.3 and I used deployment target 4.2. It did fine, the images appeared normally.

[thumbnail image in iOS 4.3 Simulator](http://flic.kr/p/axaom6)

Then I upgraded to XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 SDK and ran the app with iOS 5.0 simulator,
there's white bar in there.

[thumbnail image in iOS 5.0 simulator](http://flic.kr/p/axaom2)

I don't know what is this thing exactly maybe some kind of border or something that I don't know. Any help or clue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's an update for this, but someone said it is only working in the simulator not in real device.(http://forums.three20.info/discussion/400/strange-white-bar-shows-when-using-ttthumbsviewcontroller-with-ios-5-sdk)
Here's the source.
https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/634

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I did to make it work..

Create a subclass of TTThumbsViewController, then do the following:

1. in ViewDidLoad, include this line

   self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
2. Overwrite - (void)updateTableLayout to the following

   -(void)updateTableLayout {
       self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(/*TTBarsHeight()+*/4, 0, 0, 0);
       self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TTBarsHeight(), 0, 0, 0); 
   }

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I'm gonna test it in real device to check it as soon as I get the device.